# JBOSS CLI adding module with optional dependency

Tags: deployment, wildfly, jboss7.x, jboss-eap-6

I have a module.xml that looks like:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.oracle">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="ojdbc6.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
    </dependencies>
```

Using JBOSS-CLI one can do this:

```
./jboss-cli.sh -c --command="module add --name=com.oracle --resources=<path-to-file>/ojdbc6.jar --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api,javax.servlet.api"
```

to deploy the module.   It is almost the same exact thing and the module.xml is generated; so I need not keep track of another xml.

But how can I get the 'optional="true"' from JBOSS-CLI?

Version:  JBOSS-EAP 6.2.0.    (would be great if I can find a solution that would work for either jboss 6.x EAP and wildfly 8x).

Answer (score 4):

The CLI module command appears to only support simple dependencies.

You could work around it by supplying a pre-generated modules.xml file and specifying it in the CLI command using

```
--module-xml=filepath_to_modules.xml
```